# Descriptive Statistics

Tags: statistics, data-science, percentile

What would be the value at 75th percentile for a data distribution series with mean = 5, variance = 11.5, skewness = 13.5, kurtosis = 224.5, and n = 4?

I know it's not a direct formula, so do tell me how to derive the result and also the supporting theory/logic.

Comment: I only have the first half of the answer

So the 75th percentile means Quartile 3 we have to find.

Given n=4

so Q3=3/4(n+1)th  term
so   =3/4(5)
     =3.75th term

To make it whole number subtract with 0.25
which means mean of the 3rd and 4th term.

So now we have to calculate terms from 4 parameters given. Which is where I am stuck.

Comment: @MuskanAgarwal the problem is confusing , as to what the approach should be. I believe the problem requires strong grasp and conceptual clarity to imagine a statistical scenario developed above.